# Vaadin Material Theme make app not loading

Tags: spring, material-design, themes, vaadin

I generated a new Spring project with Vaadin (using start.spring.io).
I have a dependency:

```
implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter")
```

And the project works, I can run new web app.

I want to change the theme to Material according to the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/advanced/material-theme

But after that, the app stops loading and in the console, I see the error:

```
(index):6 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-material-styles" has already been used with this registry
    at window.customElements.define (http://localhost:8080/:6:829)
    at http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/@fs/Users/.../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-material-styles/version.js?v=8ff276da:19:16
```

How can I fix it?

I tried to generate a project using Vaadin starter but the same error appeared.

Comment: Did you try a full refresh "mvn vaadin:dance" after the theme change?

Comment: Yes @Knoobie I tried. I also tried to clean everything after the theme change. I suspect it's related to npm packages which loads even then.